# How to nullify the output from & command operator?

Tags: powershell

suppose i have 2 scripts

I am calling script1 in script2 like this

```
& "script1.ps1" -UpdateConnection "$DB_NAME"
```

i am using script1 to update a connection but i dont want whatever output there is to display running from script2

i tried this:

`& "script1.ps1" -UpdateConnection "$DB_NAME" > $null`

and

```
& "script1.ps1" -UpdateConnection "$DB_NAME" | out-null
```

and it doesnt do anything, the output still shows

i tried

```
"& `"script1.ps1`" -UpdateConnection `"$DB_NAME`" | out-null
```

and although no output shows the script1.ps1 doesnt execute it appears, as i didnt see the connection was changed

what can i do to circumvent this?

Comment: Basically you should not use `Write-Host` for output, as @dunck says. if you want to ignore the output of `Write-Host`, write as follows: `& "script1.ps1" -UpdateConnection "$DB_NAME" 6>$null`

Comment: @rokumaru the 6>$null somehow did the trick. i am not getting the rest of the executions, but only one liner...of course im still looking to get rid of this one liner output too

Comment: @rokumaru is there a number where i can get rid of also other outputs that are not associated with write host, such as f operator? so i want to get rid of both f operator output and write-host

Comment: @rokumaru i found it; *>$null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental problem with your scripts in that (I assume) in `script.ps1` you are using `Write-Host` where `Write-Output` should be opted for, see below examples

```
# File: test.ps1
Write-Output "hello output!"
Write-Host "hello host!"
```

```
PS C:\> & ".\test.ps1"
hello output!
hello host!

PS C:\> & ".\test.ps1" | Out-Null
hello host!
```

Comment: what about f operator